# Crystal Reports throwing DataSourceException: Failed to load database information. on Server

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, crystal-reports

I'm having a problem running Crystal Reports on my IIS server.  The report is running correctly on my local dev machine.  When I try to run the report on the file server, I'm getting the below exception.

I've verified
 - Crystal Reports is correctly installed on the server as other reports are correctly generated.   All of these reports are "simpler" than this problem report.
 - That it is not a problem with the datatable containing the data to print.   The datatable contents on the server is identical to that generating locally.

> System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.DataSourceException: Failed to load database information. Error in File temp_3652e948-46a9-48bf-bbb6-9762f068a648 5748_6200_{0D262FA7-D0A6-41FC-BC3B-36A36AA9902A}.rpt:
>   Failed to load database information. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Failed to load database information. Error in File temp_3652e948-46a9-48bf-bbb6-9762f068a648 5748_6200_{0D262FA7-D0A6-41FC-BC3B-36A36AA9902A}.rpt:
>   Failed to load database information.
>      at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.ReportSourceClass.Export(ExportOptions pExportOptions, RequestContext pRequestContext)
>      at CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.EromReportSourceBase.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext reqContext)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ConvertDotNetToErom.ThrowDotNetException(Exception e)
>      at CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.EromReportSourceBase.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext reqContext)
>      at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext reqContext)
>      at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.Export(ExportRequestContext reqContext)
>      at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.Export()
>      at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Export()

**Configuration**

- ASP.Net
- Crystal Reports
- VB.Net / VS2015

**Simplified Source code**

```
    dim pURLFileName as string = "outputfile.pdf"
    dim pDfdoCustomers as DiskFileDestinationOptions = New DiskFileDestinationOptions
    pDfdoCustomers.DiskFileName = pURLFileName

    Dim c As New IndividualSchoolMatching
    '
    ' Assign the datatable to the report
    '
    c.SetDataSource( DataTable Object )

    With c
        .ExportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile
        .ExportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat
        .ExportOptions.DestinationOptions = pDfdoCustomers

        .Export()
        .Close()
```

### End With

Update 
I'm using a TTX file to define the data from the data table.

Comment: Verify your db connections parameters in your server. Maybe you are not pointing to the same database or the server can't reach the db you are using in you pc.

Comment: I've verified that the data table contents locally and on the server are identical.  So I don't see how that could be an issue.

Comment: I'm not talking about the data. I'm talking about db configuration settings on your pc and on the server. The error shown says it has problem loading database information. Maybe a security restriction issue? check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23902850/failed-to-load-database-information-in-crystal-report-for-visual-studio-2013

Comment: Crystal Reports isn't directly accessing the database.   I'm doing that separately and passing the resulting datatable to Crystal.

Comment: Then maybe this might help you: http://erickwidya.blogspot.com/2011/01/crystal-report-2010-failed-to-load.html

Comment: Looked like a good idea, but it didn't help.

Comment: Uhmmm.. Check on this... I have the feeling that should be related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13356765/winforms-crystal-report-failed-to-load-database-information-error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to Load database information in Crystal Report for Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23902850/failed-to-load-database-information-in-crystal-report-for-visual-studio)